# Run shell script when new volume mounted

Tags: linux, debian, mount, block-device

I'm interested in running an rsync script whenever *any* new volume is mounted on my Debian box. What are some potential triggers / strategies for listening for a new volume mount?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a new rule to `/etc/udev/rules.d/`. First read the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/README`. In the new rule file, add something like

```
KERNEL=="sd?1",ACTION=="mount",RUN+="/path/to/script.sh"
```

(I did not try the above line, try your own rules.)

Note that the script will be run as `root`. You might want to use `su` to change that.

Using `ACTION=="add"` would require `script.sh` first to mount the volume.

Comment: This catches the case when the volume is *attached*, but not the *mount*. A mount might not necessarily occur when it's attached.

Comment: Marco, correct. I edited the ACTION from add to mount. I still cannot test the rule, so please be careful with that. Also `SUBSYSTEM=="block"`might be more useful than `KERNEL`.