# Is there any way to automatically copy a file to any mounted drive?

Tags: filesystems, backup, automounting

Basically, I have a small file that I'd like to back up onto various storage devices. Is there any way to make that happen automatically whenever a new drive is mounted (be it a hard disk on boot, or a flash drive while the system is already running)? Probably not the most efficient thing in the world, but it'd be cool if I could just plug a drive in and have another copy of the file without having to think about it.

Answer (score 1):

Using `RUN+=` is the wrong approach. As `man udev` makes clear:

> This can only be used for very short-running foreground tasks. Running
>   an event process for a long period of time may block all further
>   events for this or a dependent device.
>
> Starting daemons or other long running processes is not appropriate
>   for udev; the forked processes, detached or not, will be
>   unconditionally killed after the event handling has finished.

The correct approach is using `SYSTEMD_WANTS` (from `man systemd.device`):

> THE UDEV DATABASE The settings of device units may either be
>   configured via unit files, or directly from the udev database (which
>   is recommended). The following udev properties are understood by
>   systemd:
>
> SYSTEMD_WANTS= Adds dependencies of type Wants from this unit to all
>   listed units. This may be used to activate arbitrary units, when a
>   specific device becomes available. Note that this and the other tags
>   are not taken into account unless the device is tagged with the
>   "systemd" string in the udev database, because otherwise the device is
>   not exposed as systemd unit.

You just need a service file in `/etc/systemd/system/media-USBDRIVE.mount.wants/`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Backup files to USBDRIVE
Requires=media-USBDRIVE.mount
After=media-USBDRIVE.mount

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/backupscript

[Install]
WantedBy=media-USBDRIVE.mount
```

Note: this assumes your USB drive is called USBDRIVE and is mounted at `/media/USBDRIVE`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `systemd` then the person [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47337/run-shell-script-when-new-volume-mounted) has already answered this.

To place a rule

```
KERNEL=="sd?1",ACTION=="mount",RUN+="/path/to/script.sh"
```

in

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/
```

Note the caveat re execution as `root`, put whatever action you need doing in your script.